# How could an attacker circumvent crossdomain.xml

Tags: flash, cross-domain, uploadify

I am not sure if I understand the usage of `crossdomain.xml` correctly. I am, using Uploadify (2.1.4) — A flash based file uploader. I have a need to upload files from `Domain A` to `Domain B`. Uploadify is hosted and served from `Domain A`. To allow the Uploadify flash plugin to communicate and upload to `Domain B`, I must host a `crossdomain.xml` file on `Domain B`. So, if Uploadify finds a `crossdomain.xml` file on `Domain B` that has `Domain A` in it's whitelist, then the file upload to `Domain B` will be processed. All sounds good until now.

However, I fail to understand what's preventing an attacker in building a clone uploader on a local website install in his computer and subsequently modifying the `etc/hosts` to make the local install use `Domain A` as the domain name. Now, the attacker could upload files to `Domain B`, pretending to be `Domain A` and `Domain B` would frankly accept the upload as it has `Domain A` listed in the whitelist within `crossdomain.xml`.

What's the purpose of `crossdomain.xml`, if it could be easily circumvented like above? I could be completely wrong in my understanding of this. An insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`crossdomain.xml` can't replace login system. It just tells Flash: 'Hey, you can read (and use) data from my server'.

crossdomain.xml is **really** easy to bypass, so it can't be treated as a proper security feature for the website.

So, to summarize, if you want to be secure just implement login feature on your 'DomainB'.

Comment: Ah! now I get it. But could you please elaborate on why the system was put in place when it's extremely easy to defeat it. There must be something for which it was implemented in the first place.